# identity with gamma function

Tags: calculus

I used the program "Mathematica" to get a closed form to

$\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}{\frac{a^j}{j!}}, \ \ a>0 $      (and real)

and the solution I got is:

$\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}{\frac{a^j}{j!}}=\frac{e^a(\Gamma(k)-\Gamma(k,a))}{\Gamma(k)}$

where $\Gamma(k)$ is the Gamma function and $\Gamma(k,a)$ is the incomplete Gamma function.

Can anyone prove this identity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\sum_{j = k}^{\infty} \frac{a^j}{j!} = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a^j}{j!} - \sum_{j = 0}^{a - 1} \frac{a^j}{j!}  = e^a - \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \frac{a^j}{j!}$$

So it suffices to prove that

$$\sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \frac{a^j}{j!} = e^a \frac{\Gamma(k, a)}{(k - 1)!} \quad\quad (*)$$

This is established by induction on $k$; the base case of $k = 1$ is immediate. From the recurrence relation given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_Gamma_function#Properties), we have that

$$\Gamma(k + 1, a) = k \Gamma(k, a) + a^k e^{-a}$$

So assuming $(*)$ in the $k$ case, we then have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j = 0}^k \frac{a^j}{j!} &= e^a \frac{\Gamma(k, a)}{(k - 1)!} + \frac{a^k}{k!} \\
&= e^a \frac{\Gamma(k + 1, a) - a^k e^{-a}}{k!} + \frac{a^k}{k!} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(k + 1, a)}{k!}
\end{align*}

as desired.